# "local variable 'x' referenced before assignment" when data become larger

Tags: python-3.x

I just wrote a code to decode something. When I try some small number, it works well. However, when I try some big number, it throws a wrong.

The thing what I would like to decode is this:
[image]

```
def decode(n):
    if n == 0:
        return (0, 0)
    circle = int(sqrt(n) / 2 + 0.5)
    largest = (2 * circle + 1) ** 2 - 1
    distance = largest - n
    quotient = distance // (2 * circle)
    remainder = distance % (2 * circle)

    if quotient == 0:
        x = circle- remainder
        y = - circle
    if quotient == 1:
        x = -circle
        y = -circle + remainder
    if quotient == 2:
        x = -circle + remainder
        y = circle
    if quotient == 3:
        x = circle
        y = circle - remainder
    return (x, y)

print(decode(2070)) #(23, 23)    
print(decode(204019576686482721392)) #(7141771, 7141771081)
print(decode(142656302882002193830320)) 
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File line 51, in <module>
#    print(decode(142656302882002193830320))
#  File line 47, in decode
#    return (x, y)
#UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

I also have tried n from 1-14, all the result is right.

I just found the reason that I should provide another `int()` in sqrt(n).

```
circle = int(int(sqrt(n) / 2) + 0.5)
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: So what's the value of `quotient` there?

Comment: If your quotient is greater than 3, you don't end up setting the value of `x`. Hence you get the error when you try and return `x`.

Comment: Thanks  for you remind. I just tried that the quotient is 4, so this is the reason why there is an error. But why quotient will become 4, I am confused. Please give me more hints.

Comment: This looks like one of the Euler project challenges - although I might be mis-remembering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a situation where none of your if statements are matched so when you try to return `x` it hasn't been defined. You should give `x` and `y` default values.

You should also use `elif` (else if) clauses otherwise every `if` block will need to be checked. Using `elif`s means that once a statement is matched, the rest are skipped; It's more efficient and less prone to two statements accidentally matching at the same time.

```
def decode(n):
    # either pre-define your default values...
    x = 0
    y = 0

    if quotient == 0:
        x = circle - remainder
        y = - circle
    elif quotient == 1:
        x = -circle
        y = -circle + remainder
    elif quotient == 2:
        x = -circle + remainder
        y = circle
    elif quotient == 3:
        x = circle
        y = circle - remainder
    # ...or define your defaults in an else clause
    else:
        x = 0
        y = 0

    return (x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any possible way to debug why quotient value will out of my expectation when the input become large.